# audio onended not firing in Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, html5-audio

I am currently making a simple music app with the Ionic framework as practice. This is my first time working with Ionic and first time working with AngularJS. Right now i want to make sure that when a song from a certain playlist is finished, the next one starts. However, the `onended` HTMLproperty doesn't seem to do anything.

**First Try**

menu.html

```html
 <audio ng-src="{{ audioSrc }}" controls class="player" id="trackPlayer" autoplay="true" onended="nextTrack()">
   <source type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

controller.js

```js
 //check if audio is finished
    $scope.nextTrack = function () {
      //find the right playlist and right current song id
      alert("ended");
      console.log($rootScope.nowPlaying);
      //set new audiosrc for audioplayer
    }
```

I'm also trying to target the audioplayer directly by javascript, but this doesn't work either.

**Second try**

controller.js

```js
document.getElementById('trackPlayer').addEventListener('onended', $scope.nextTrack());
```

Putting an `alert('ended!')` in `onended` in my audio tag works but anything else does not give a response when my audio is done playing.
I have looked all over but did not find a solution or an explenation yet.
Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While I don't use either of the frameworks you mention, your second try is never going to work. You're passing the _result_ of calling `nextTrack` to `addEventListener`, when what you need to do is pass the _function itself_. So, what I'd be doing is changing `.addEventListener('onended', $scope.nextTrack());` to `.addEventListener('onended', $scope.nextTrack );` (Note the removed brackets) - It may well be that your first try would work if `onended="nextTrack()">` was changed to `onended="$scope.nextTrack()">`